# How to prove that "The union of a countably infinite collection of (pairwise different) nonempty sets is infinite"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

Consider the following proposition

> The union of a countably infinite collection of (*pairwise different*) nonempty sets is infinite.

I think it is correct. But how to prove it rigorously?

Comment: If it were finite then every one of your collection would be a subset of a fixed finite set, but there are only finitely many such.

Comment: @lulu Hadn't thought of that ... Thanks. Writing it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

Suppose the claim were false.  That is, suppose that the union was a finite set $S$. Then every set in your collection would be a subset of the finite set $S$ but there are only $2^{|S|}-1$ of these (you have excluded the empty set). Thus we have a contradiction.